# Add permanent subtitles to a videoclip

Tags: video, encoding, video-editing, subtitle

I would like to add permanent subtitles to a videoclip. I don't want to use .srt files or similar formats, I'd like to attach the text I want to the movie.

Is there a program that can do this easily on the mac?

Comment: Handbrake does this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-use-handbrake-to-attach-subtitles-to-a-movie-file/) is a detailed manual how to use handbrake to add subtitles.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, schluchc! While this may answer the question, [it is best](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to summarize the contents of the link and provide the link for reference. Links have a tendency disappear over time, leaving a non-applicable answer for those who may stumble upon your answer in the future.